# void or expires after use on a coupon

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

I want to say a coupon can only be used one time, what should I put on it? Coupon expires after use, or Coupon void after use?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Is part of the requirement that the verb-to-be must not be used?

Comment: Yes. Is it common to omit the verb be on coupons?

Comment: Your recent series of questions seems to be about a lack of perfect clarity  when a very terse, elliptical disclaimer is used.  So I was wondering if you're aiming for clarity or trying to stick within the "genre" of coupon-speak.

Answer (score 4):

*[Expires](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expire)* indicates that the coupon is no longer valid after a given amount of time.

*[Void](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/void)* indicates that the coupon was actively invalidated for some reason. For example, you can write "VOID" across a check, and that particular paper check can no longer be used as legal tender. No bank will accept it, so merchants will also not accept it. The relevant definition from the link:

> Of no legal force or effect, incapable of confirmation or ratification.

Furthermore, in the context of coupons and tendering, "void" typically means "this tender was used and later removed." For example: if you go to a store and pay with a credit card, then reverse the charge and pay with cash instead, the credit charge should show up as "void" on the receipt.

---

A better way to word this is "this coupon is valid for a single use" or "this coupon may be redeemed one time." That avoids terms that have other meanings in the context of tenders, and gets straight to the point that the coupon may not be redeemed multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

> Coupon valid for **one** {X}

whatever X is.

> Coupon valid for one free car wash.
>
> Coupon valid for  50% off  the price of one matinee ticket

Typically the person at the cash register takes the coupon from the customer, so you don't have to worry about the customer trying to use it multiple times. Your main concern is that you want the customer to know that he or she cannot use the coupon for more than one of X, for example, "Shouldn't I be able to get 50% off the ticket price for me and my wife????"

And the coupon will usually have a barcode or QR code, so you don't have to worry about the person at the cash register reselling them on the black market. The code shouldn't "scan" more than once, and even if it does, you have an audit trail and will be able to nab the perp.